# In Emberjs, how can I pass data from one view to another?

Tags: ember.js

I have a view that renders a `Comment`. One of the pieces of information is the time at which the comment was updated, and I want to render it using a view.

In my "comment" handlebars template, I'm trying this:

```
{{view App.TimeView titleBinding="comment.updated_time"}}
```

And then in my "time" handlebars template I expected to be able to do `{{title}}`, but that's undefined.

My `TimeView` looks like this:

```
App.TimeView = Em.View.extend({                                                                       
    templateName: 'time',                                                                                
    tagName: 'abbr',
    classNames: ['timeago'],                                                                                
    attributeBinding: ['title'],                                                                            

    didInsertElement: function() {
        this._super();                                                                                      
        this.$().timeago();                                                                                 
    }
});
```

The final result I would like is this:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="TIMESTAMP_GOES_HERE">
    TIMESTAMP_GOES_HERE
</abbr>
```

But there must be some gap in my understanding of Ember, because that's not happening.

What's the proper way to achieve what I have in mind?

Comment: It should be `{{view.title}}`. The default path in Handlebars is the controller, therefore `{{title}}` is equivalent to `{{controller.title}}`.

Comment: @Zack, Thanks, I tried, and `{{view.title}}` is `undefined`, although `{{log view}}` shows that there are `set title` and `get title` methods. Any other idea?

Comment: Try log `{{log comment.updated_time}}` before `{{view App.TimeView ...}}`. If that works, you need to post a fiddle to help you.

Comment: @Zack, I wrote the minimal app fiddle, and it actually worked, and that made me realize I had an unrelated error in the rest of my code. I was misusing `this` in the contest of views. Thanks! If you post your initial comment as an answer, I'll accept it.